# On the continuity of functions in intervals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, continuity

I have encountered the definition of a function being continuous in a closed interval and it has brought some confusion with it. It states that a function is continuous in a closed interval $[a,b]$ iff $\forall \xi \in [a,b],\,\varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 \; \forall x \in [a,b]: \; |x - \xi| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(\xi)| < \varepsilon$. What I cannot quite wrap my head around is the fact that we (for some reason) restrict the variable $x$ to the interval $[a,b]$ as well. Why are we doing this? That would mean, for example, that at the endpoints $a$ and $b$ of the interval the function is right/left-continuous, which is certainly not enough to establish the fact that the function is continuous at those points, but the textbook also expressly stated that if a function is continuous in an interval, then it is continuous at every point of that interval. How can I deal with this confusion?

Comment: Where is the function defined?. If you have given $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then that statement is correct. If you have $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the condition implies that $f|_{[a,b]}$ is continuous, but it doesn't imply that $f$ is continuous in $a$, as you pointed out.

Comment: @user940347 That is the problem! Nowhere in the textbook is its said whether the interval is the domain of the function or just the subset of the latter, but it had some strong decline towards generality and the domain of the function was not specified.

Comment: Maybe "continuous on the closed intervall" should refer to the fact that $f|_{[a,b]}$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. It is a definition, so there is no reason, why this should not be allowed. Just accept it and look how they use it later on and if this will lead to problems.

Comment: This is a good question. The *only* textbook I have seen that actually warns about this confusion is Stromberg's *Introduction to Classical Real Analysis* (“**(3.67) Warning**” on p. 116). He's explicitly adopting the convention that “$f$ is continuous on $S$” means that the restriction $f|_S$ is a continuous function.

Comment: You are looking at a definition and not a theorem: $f$ is said to be continuous on $[a, b]$ if it continuous for every $x \in (a, b)$, right-continuous at $a$ and left-continuous at $b$. This is not the same as saying that $f$ is (two-sided) continuous at each $x \in [a, b]$ and is designed to deal with situations where $f$ isn't necessarily defined outside $[a, b]$.